# Pass a input parameter in Stored Procedure using Entity Framework SqlQuery

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, model-view-controller

How do I pass the input parameter in Stored Procedure in my Business layer in MVC.
    Normal select query works fine like this, how do i pass a input parameter in it.
    Eg:

```
public List<Customer> GetCustomer()
    {
        List<Customer> Cust = null;
        Cust = db.Database.SqlQuery<Customer>("sp_cust").ToList();
        return Cust;
    }
 SP
 create procedure sp_cust
 as
 begin
 select ID from tblCustomer WITH (NOLOCK)
 end

 Input parameter SP

 create procedure sp_cust
 @name varchar(20)
 as
 begin 
 select ID from tblCustomer WITH (NOLOCK)
 where name = @name 
 end

 I tried

 public List<Customer> GetCustomer()
    {
        List<Customer> Cust = null;
        string name = "MVC";
        Cust = db.Database.SqlQuery<Customer>("sp_cust",name).ToList();
        Cust = db.Database.SqlQuery<Customer>("sp_cust",@name).ToList();
        Cust = db.Database.SqlQuery<Customer>("sp_cust","@name").ToList();
        return Cust;
    }
```

why Didnt worked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use a named parameter placeholder and then bind it to a `SqlParameter`:

```
 mediaCat = db.Database
      .SqlQuery<Customer>("exec sp_cust @name",
         new SqlParameter("@name", name)).ToList();
```

Note however that it [isn't good practice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172115(v=vs.100).aspx) to prefix your stored procs in Sql Server with `sp` (assuming this is the RDBMS), and use of uncommitted reads `(NOLOCK)` can cause unexpected results - if you have locking or performance related issues in your database, rather fix the indexing and queries.

**Edit More than one Param**

[SqlQuery takes a `params object[]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696545(v=vs.113).aspx), so you can pass as many parameters as you like:

```
  .SqlQuery<Customer>("exec sp_cust @param1, @param2",
     new SqlParameter("@param1", valueForParam1),
     new SqlParameter("@param2", valueForParam2)
     ).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi, this works fine and thanks for the suggestion,now how can I pass more than one input parameter.

Comment: Thank you its working fine,hope this the correct and best way to execute a SP in MVC.

Comment: `SqlQuery` certainly a useful backdoor to quickly bind the results of adhoc queries and stored procs etc to "POCO classes" using EF's existing Connection infrastructure. But I wouldn't be using lots of PROCs to do basic CRUD operations on the database - suggest model the tables directly as entities and use EF - its much easier. SPROC's should be used where there is a lot of value add being done in TSQL.

Comment: It looks like the params object[] expects the params supplied to be in the same order that the params are defined in the SP. ... seems un-intuitive since you're naming the params

Comment: [The docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696545%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) (admittedly not very helpful or complete) seem to infer that if the `params` objects are `DbParameters` they are named, whereas if they are naked values, then they are positional. I'm a bit far removed from EF right now but would be worth a test and to then update the docs definitively.